# Magnifying text in a UILabel on touch for iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

Is it possible to magnify texts seen in `uilabel` while touching the same ? I am trying to implement a magnifying glass kind of effect!!

Comment: Are you trying to implement a magnifying glass kind of thing?

Comment: Ya Deepak!!  you have that code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to increase label frame and also font size when you touch and if count is %2==0 then reset label frame to original ..

Comment: This kind of answer is generally not the kind that we look for on StackOverflow. It provides a little bit of help, but you could make it better by adding sample code, delegate methods the asker should modify, and why certain things are being done (the even number check is the biggest standout). Add more detail, I'm sure you'll get many more upvotes.

Comment: @Aurum Aquila : Thanks for your suggestion . i just gave an idea thats all which i got ..however i searched and found a link         @Sadumerry check this link http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/03/a-simpler-magnifying-glass-loupe-view-for-the-iphone

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Narayanan MOorthy!! It helped a lot.